# Qt space around QWidget

Tags: qt, widget, space

When my class inherits `QWidget` it has extra space around. When it inherits `QVBoxLayout` there is no space. The contents margins are 0. What's the source of the space, how to remove it?

[Functionality example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk2VV.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. My widget has a layout and that layout for some reason has contents margins set to 11 by default (I have no idea why, because always the are set to 0 by default).

widgetLayout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0);

Comment: It seems that method setLayout modifies contentsMargins of the layout.